# How to Detect / Read / Write multiple HID devices

Tags: .net, delphi, vb6, usb, hid

I am using Temper Gold 1.1 PCsensor USB.  i can connect all of them to my pc, i am able to handle Single USB device,the devices are detected as HID but when there are more than one i am lost.

I can not identify which device i am reading from. or how to fix devices identification as usb devices are interchangeable i don't get how do i get them to work.

I am trying to build multiple usb reading display on Monitor, reading from usb controller and displaying on screen. as a 2x3 gird on whole screen.

any help from would be much appreciated.

Language of development is Visual Basic 6, or Visual Basic .Net, Delphi 7

Comment: Is each device enumerated as a separate HID in Windows in the first place? If they are separate USB devices, you should be able to identify each USB HID device by their VID, PID and USB Serial Number.

Comment: yes they are identified as separate devices but usb have no serial number or i don't know it.

Comment: Do they have the same or separate PIDs? You can use USBlyzer to find the serial number if the PIDs are identical: http://www.usblyzer.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Vendor id is 0c45 and pid is 7401 for all connected devices that is have

Comment: Then you will need to identify each device by the serial number

Comment: @SteveMagness Can you share some example how you recommend to do that.

Comment: To find the Serial Number, use USBlyzer as I suggested earlier. If you're struggling to open the device once you've found the serial number you're going to need to show some code for how you currently open the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [VB6 TEMPer Gold USB HID Thermometer Class](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?685671-VB6-TEMPer-Gold-USB-HID-Thermometer-Class) yet?

This may not address the issue of "following" a specific device when moved from one USB port to another, but you may find something useful there.

These devices are problematic though.  They can spontaneously burst into sending data via the HID keyboard virtual device, which can wreak havoc when those keystrokes end up reaching the shell (Explorer Desktop).

Until the keyboard feature can be disabled on these devices they aren't ready for any kind of production use.  I have never found any way to accomplish that.

Comment: That is very nice of you to point me that. i checked that class. it works find with one usb. but my problem is still there. 

and you are write about the brusting info. i think if i open one device at a time  and read data for a while then close that device will it be a good idea, or practice since you seem to have more experience/skill with this stuff.

Comment: That's an entirely different question.  There is no short answer anyway since VB6 multithreading isn't a trivial matter.  One way makes use of an ActiveX EXE and is covered in the documentation.  Other alternatives require 3rd party libraries.